# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403

Tags: api, axios, rapidapi

I tried using this api-key provided by RapidAPI for my code. I made sure that the API key entered is correct. I was previously using the .env file,'X-RapidAPI-Host': process.env.COIN_RANKING_HOST, for both the api host and api key but to make sure that the error is not caused by the .env file not loading, I entered both directly. This is my code:

```
import Header from '../components/Header'
import PortfolioChart from '../components/PortfolioChart'
import BuyTokens from '../components/BuyTokens'
import Notice from '../components/Notice'
import Asset from '../components/Asset'

import { BiDotsHorizontalRounded } from 'react-icons/bi'
import { AiOutlinePlus } from 'react-icons/ai'
import axios from 'axios'

const styles = {
  wrapper: 'w-screen h-screen flex flex-col',
  mainContainer: 'w-2/3 h-full m-auto flex mt-16',
  leftMain: 'flex flex-col w-3/4 h-full  p-6 overflow-y-scroll',
  portfolioAmountContainer: 'flex flex-col ',
  portfolioAmount: 'text-white text-4xl',
  portfolioPercent: 'text-white font-bold text-sm',
  pastHour: 'text-gray-400',
  chartContainer:
    'text-5xl flex justify-center w-full h-1/3 text-white mt-11 mb-11',
  buyingPowerContainer:
    'w-full border-t mb-24 border-b h-16 border-[#30363b] flex justify-between items-center p-4',
  buyingPowerTitle: 'text-white font-bolder text-lg',
  buyingPowerAmount: 'text-white font-bolder text-xl',
  notice: 'flex border border-[#30363b] mx-11 my-4 p-5 flex-col flex-1',
  noticeContainer: 'flex-1',
  noticeTitle: 'text-gray-500',
  noticeMessage: 'text-white font-bold',
  noticeCTA: 'font-bold text-green-500 cursor-pointer mt-5',
  rightMain:
    'flex flex-col flex-1 h-4/5 bg-[#1E2123] mt-6 rounded-lg overflow-y-scroll noScroll',
  rightMainItem: 'flex items-center text-white p-5 border-b border-[#30363b]',
  ItemTitle: 'flex-1 font-bold',
  moreOptions: 'cursor-pointer text-xl',
}

  export default function Home({coins}) {
    console.log(coins)
    return(
      <div className={styles.wrapper}>
        <Header />
        <div className={styles.mainContainer}>
          <div className={styles.leftMain}>
          <div className={styles.portfolioAmountContainer}>
            <div className={styles.portfolioAmount}>
              23 SOLANA
            </div>
            <div className={styles.portfolioPercent}>
              +0.0008(+0.57%)
              <span className={styles.pastHour}>
                Past Hour
              </span>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div>
            <div className={styles.chartContainer}>
            <PortfolioChart />
            </div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.buyingPowerContainer}>
            <div className={styles.buyingPowerTitle}>Buying Power</div>
            <div className={styles.buyingPowerAmount}>12 SOLANA</div>
          </div>
          <div className={styles.notice}>
            <div className={styles.noticeContainer}>
              <div className={styles.noticeTitle}>
                Send Funds
              </div>
              <div className={styles.noticeMessage}>
                Transfer your funds here.
              </div>
              <BuyTokens />
            </div>
          </div>
          <Notice />
          </div>
        <div className={styles.rightMain}>
          <div className={styles.rightMainItem}>
            <div className={styles.ItemTitle}>
              Crypto Currencies
            </div>
            <BiDotsHorizontalRounded className={styles.moreOptions} />
          </div>
          <Asset coin={"BTC"}  price={0.89} />
          <Asset coin={"SOL"}  price={0.90} />
          <Asset coin={"ETH"}  price={-1} />
          <Asset coin={"USDC"}  price={2} />
          <div className={styles.rightMain}>
            <div className={styles.ItemTitle}>
              Lists
            </div>
            <AiOutlinePlus className={styles.moreOptions} />
          </div>
        </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

  export const getStaticProps = async () => {
    const options = {
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com/coins',
      params: {
        referenceCurrencyUuid: 'yhjMzLPhuIDl',
        timePeriod: '24h',
        tiers: '1',
        orderBy: 'marketCap',
        orderDirection: 'desc',
        limit: '50',
        offset: '0',
      },
      headers: {
        'X-RapidAPI-Host': 'coinranking1.p.rapidapi.com',
        'X-RapidAPI-Key': '23734db4e2msha5580c4a7b981c0p1557d0jsn9c9dcf2b8505',
      },
    }
  
    const res = await axios.request(options)
    const coins = res.data.data.coins
  
    return {
      props: { coins },
    }
  }
```

The error showing in the terminal is this.The error was very lengthy and I couldn't post the entire error due to character limit. I have put up the initial two lines and the last two lines of the error though.

error - [AxiosError: Request failed with status code 403] {
code: 'ERR_BAD_REQUEST',
...
data: { message: 'You are not subscribed to this API.' }
},
page: '/'
}

I am unable to figure out why I am getting this error. Please help.

[I am subscribed to RapidAPI.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBJZa.png)

Comment: It looks like an authorization error, please make sure you are using the correct credentials and format.

Comment: check it out on RapidAPI once, have you really subscribed?

Comment: I have, I have added a screenshot in the question, they wouldn't provide you with a key if you don't sign up

Comment: My bad! I was simply logged in, completed a few more steps and subscribed! The error resolved itself!